# Nativebase Only one default export allowed per module

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have a react js app and i need to make 2 exports. The first is

```
export  default reduxForm({
  form: 'simple'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm)
```

to handle form submission and the next is to bind some ui actions

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, bindAction)(Inbox);
```

When i have the two exports, i get the error that i cant have 2 exports in one module. Can the problem be solved by combining the two exports?.

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one exports. When you want to export only single function/class/const etc, you should use default export. For multiple exports use exports only.

```
export reduxForm() 
export connect()
```

of course, you have to add codes with them :p
and just `import { reduxForm, connect } from 'path'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `default` keywords on both `reduxForm()` and `connect()` classes, as per code below:

```
export reduxForm({
  form: 'simple'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm)

export connect(mapStateToProps, bindAction)(Inbox);
```

`default` keywords is only use when you want to export ONE class.